# One generic type parameter, different generic for return type?

Tags: c#, generics

So for two different namespaces, I have a class Record. I'd like to return the appropriate one based off the type being passed in. To try and do this, I've attempted this, but the "T2" is incorrect. How can I achieve this?

```
public T2 GetGeneratedType<T1>(string name) where T1 : class where T2 : class
{
  var type = typeof(T1);
  var generatedName = type.AssemblyQualifiedName.Replace(type.Name, name);
  return (T2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(generatedName));
}
```

I haven't tested this (won't compile, obviously), but how do I make this work so that if I pass Namespace1.SomeClass in, I get Namespace1.Record and in the case I pass in Namespace2.SomeOtherClass, I get Namespace2.Record (so long as name == "Record").

I initially attempted T for everything and it didn't give any error messages, but I want to make sure the input and output types are allowed to be different types.

Edit:

I may've not explained entirely.

I'm creating a data annotation for a forked record (technically, 3 people need to be able to be assigned this record at any given time due to 3 distinct processes being performed on them. They're reconciled once the 3 processes are completed). So namespace1 is one project (not in the Visual Studio sense) and namespace2 is another. In namespace1 you have an ImportedRecord1 and in namespace2 ImportedRecord2 (both separate projects with seperate properties, though more or less serve the same purpose). Namespace1 and Namespace2 both have a Record type relating to the ImportedRecord for that particular namespace which will then fork into the 3 "subrecords" of a different type (basically the imported record of that project but with a field that relates to one of the 3 processes).

Comment: So, you want the compiler to figure out the return type of your method based on what the method does at runtime? I'm afraid that's simply not possible.

Comment: So there'd be no way to pass in Namespace1.ImportedRecord1 as the generic and the string "Record" and being returned a new Namespace1.Record? That's a bummer, but I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: As the compile time type? No. As the runtime type of the returned object? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the return type to dynamic instead of T2. The type will be determined at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to declare the second type as part of the generic method signature.

```
public T2 GetGeneratedType<T1, T2>(string name) where T1 : class where T2 : class
{
  var type = typeof(T1);
  var generatedName = type.AssemblyQualifiedName.Replace(type.Name, name);
  return (T2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(generatedName));
}
```

**EDIT:**

This doesn't really relate directly to your question but I will throw it in anyhow. I don't think that this design is really giving you any value code reduction or otherwise...

- You won't be decoupling the classes like you might with a Factory simply because now you returning an `object` type which you'll be forced to cast on the other side.
- You also lose slight performance in leveraging reflection to create these objects at runtime.
- Just a one-off function for this specific scenario and practices like these can lead to kludgy code if perpetuated.

Comment: Only problem is that I'm not sure of what T2 will be until runtime. I think I found an answer for this in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107170/property-type-as-generic-parameter?rq=1 . Apparently it is as easy as returning an object.

Comment: @Robert What is the value in passing in the name of the class and having a few lines of code generate the object ... if you are left with hard casting it back in the class which this method call originated in? You are just stuck with obfuscated coupling rather than straight forward tighter coupling =D

Comment: @Robert What is your primary goal with introducing this method?

Comment: tried to add a comment but too many characters, edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Generic type parameters can only go "into" function calls.  It's possible for a function to have a generic return value, but the type of the return value has to be supplied by the caller [it is, of course, possible for a function which returns some class type `T` to return a reference to an instance of any type derived from `T`, but the caller would still see the type of return value as `T`.]  In many cases, one can specify a rather non-specific return type and have the caller cast it if the caller knows or can determine the type more precisely, but this approach has some limitations.  For example, one may know that a returned object will be of a type which satisfies independent constraints `IFoo` and `IBar`, but the types of things that may be returned may not share any common supertype that also implements `IFoo` and `IBar`.  There's no nice identity-preserving way to pass such a return value to a method which needs something satisfying both `IFoo` and `IBar` constraints, since there is no single type to which all possible values may be cast.

One way of working around this limitation is to have a function expose an object not by returning it to the caller, but rather by passing it to a generic method in a caller-supplied object.  For example, if one defines an interfaces:

```
interface IFooBarConsumer { PerformAction <T>(T thing) where T:IFoo,IBar; }
interface IFooBarFeeder { FeedItem(IFooBarConsumer theConsumer); }
```

If a class which implements `IFooBarFeeder` has an object which it knows satisfies `IFoo` and `IBar`, it can pass that object to a passed-in `IFooBarConsumer`, and that consumer will in turn be able to pass it to methods which have both `IFoo` and `IBar` constraints.  Having to give code a consumer, rather than simply receiving an object from it, may be awkward, but it allows one to do some things in type-safe fashion that would otherwise not be possible.